# Which layout qualifier should be used with Android 3.0 or above?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio-3.0, screen-size, android-layout-weight, screen-density

I was using layout `normal`, `large`, `x-large` but it was not working. I found out that Android works on the smallest dp. So I searched and found these two methods for layouts qualifier.

First method is to use `layout-mdpi`, `layout-hdpi`, `layout-xhdpi`, `layout-xxhdpi`. Second method is to use `layout-sw320dp`, `layout-sw480dp`, `layout-sw600dp`, `layout-sw720dp`.

Now I am confused about which method is the standard way to use layout-qualifiers? I have searched around [Google Docs Screen Density](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

I am not able to get final decision what to use for layout from the above-mentioned methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which layout qualifier (for different screen sizes) you should use does not depend on which Android Studio version you're using. It depends on what you need.

In your case, if you want to support devices (for different **screen sizes**) which run on API level 12 or lower, you have to use the legacy size qualifiers (e.g. `x-large`). If you want to run it on devices using APIs above level 12, you can use the smallest and/or available width qualifier (e.g. `w-600dp` and `sw-600dp` respectively). [Read more here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#available-width). All the qualifiers in this paragraph are standardized; it just depends on what you need.

The qualifiers `mdpi`, `hdpi`, and so on are **not** used as qualifiers for different **screen sizes** layout, but for **resources** (in particular, images). This is so that Android can auto-generate versions of your rasterized images to [display good graphical qualities for screens with different pixel densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

Comment: but sw320dp and sw480dp contain too many different screen sizes ranges from 3.7" to 6" (for all these device only one layout not working. How to manage this

Comment: @Shani74 You can use any value for `N` in `sw<N>dp`. This means that you can make as many layouts as possible for many different screen sizes. Have you read the link I gave (because it's mentioned there too)? For instance, you can use `sw480dp`, `sw560dp`, `sw640dp`, `sw720dp`, `sw960dp` and so forth.

Comment: @Shani74 If my answer helped, do consider accepting and/or upvoting it ;-)

Comment: yes I read that link many time but I want to know about the actual value of N as u mentioned anyone I want. I got your point. last thing as my actual  Question was, Which is recommended and standard method? layout-sw480dp, layout-sw560dp or layout-hdp, layout-xhdp, layout-xxhdp because Now I am using xxhdp,xhdp method and its working with different screen size according to my needs.

Comment: @Shani74 The recommended methods are using smallest and/or available width qualifier (e.g. `w-600dp` and `sw-600dp`. But if you need to support older devices, you can use legacy size qualifiers `x-large`. Using `xxhpdi` is not mentioned in the doc, but still viable.